# Column 'registry_num' is ambiguous

Tags: sql

This is my code but the error that `registry_num` is ambiguous. Also when I get rid of registry_num the results only return the data from my offenders table.

```
select first_name, last_name, address1,
  address2, city, state,
  start_date, end_date, registry_num
from offenders left outer join addresses
on address1 = 'disney' or 'cruise';
```

Comment: suppose you share the `offenders.java` file.is there a field called `registry_num`.May be you have to change the field name to `registrynum` and try.

Comment: Please include your table structure(s).

Comment: You have column registrynum in both the tables which are part of join ?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly guesswork but based on the error you're getting, a (more) correct version might be:

```
    Select o.registry_num
         , o.first_name
         , o.last_name
         , a.address1
         , a.address2
         , a.city
         , a.state
         , o.start_date
         , o.end_date
      From offenders o
 Left join addresses a
        On a.registry_num = o.registry_num
     Where a.address1 in ( 'disney', 'cruise')
         ;
```